# How to modify the paper dimensions in plain TeX?

Tags: tex

I mean the whole paper, not only the text zone in it.

I want the dvi output to look 1 centimetre x 10 metres in the viewer if
I set these dimensions in the tex file.

And I don't want to go through LaTeX for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add \special{papersize=1cm,1000cm} in the first page of the document. This is really a dvips extension, but many dvi viewers understand it. (And of course set \hsize, \vsize etc. to control the positioning of text.)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of useful links:
[The size of printed output](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=papersize) and 
[Getting the right paper geometry from (La)TeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=papergeom).

Of course, googling is much more efficient once I get the answer.

Comment: I came across this question as I was looking for info about using dvipng, which it turns out [does not honor the \special{papersize=width,height}](https://www.mail-archive.com/dvipng@nongnu.org/msg00130.html) command. Figured I'd note that down here in case others come here pursuing the same inquiry,